# Launching certain programs on startup in their own fullscreen space

Tags: macos, terminal, spaces, fullscreen

When I login I want a blank desktop in my first space, sublime text in my second space, chrome in my third, and terminal in my fourth space like so:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For google and other search engines we prefer one (1) question per topic. That will also eliminate the complicated answers. So nothing personal but it helps us managing this site. Thank you..PS I have to vote it down till you remove the multiple questions.

Comment: Updated with only the initial question ;)

Comment: Nice,... now lets see if someone will take the time with the answer. and you got +10 for doing it :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to you second desktop
2. Right click the Sublime Text icon on your dock
3. Go to Options > Open at Login
4. Right click the Sublime icon again
5. Go to Options > Assign to: This Desktop

Do the same for every app you want to open at login on the appropriate desktop.